# Laravel - Password protect a Route

Tags: laravel, passwords

I have an application which doesn't have user roles, as all functions apart from 1 are open to all users.

As we have added an SMS notification function which comes with a cost, I want to limit who can use this function behind a password.

So currently in my Form I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Send SMS Notification</h2>
                    <p class="text-center">Please note a password is required for this function</p>
                    <div class="card-header card-header-rose card-header-text">
                        <div class="card-text">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Enter Message</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::open(array('action' => ['NotificationController@sms'],'method'=>'POST', 'class'=>'form-horizontal')) !!}
                    <div class = "card-body">
                        @if (count($errors)>0)
                            <div class = "alert alert-danger">
                                <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        <div class = "row">
                            <label class = "col-sm-2 col-form-label">Message: </label>
                            <div class = "col-sm-6">
                                <div class = "form-group">
                                    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" maxlength="160" name="message">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "card-footer">
                        <div class = "row">
                            <div class = "col-md-4">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                        <a href="{{action('HomeController@index')}}" class = "btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class ="col-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send SMS Notification</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {!!Form::close()!!}


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So the idea is when the Send SMS Notification is press, the system will ask for a password which the user needs to enter.

I have no idea how to add this function, and google hasn't helped.
Currently, the code for sending a message is fine and not facing any issues here.

Other suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any auth framework installed (i.e. [Fortify](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify) or [Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/introduction.html))?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **Laravel Basic Auth**.
Basic Auth comes with Laravel auot of the box.

You need an users table with their emails and passwords.
You can protect routes with that midleware witch only accept authenticater users to get next request.

In your case if you want to limit users acces to sms sending feature you will have to add some kind of differentiation in your user model something like
a policy where you control which users can or cannot send sms.

Http basic auth expect find an email as username in Basic Auth form.

The only thing, you need to do is

```
Route::get('/sendsms', [SmsController::class,'index'])->middleware('auth.basic');
```

More about this in [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#http-basic-authentication)

Comment: I am using Auth now for users to log in, but i want to limit the functions to a handful of people using a different password

Comment: But you will have to add some field to your users table to discriminate based on that feature. ¿How are going to filter your users ?¿Are going to implement another auth system only for that feature?  I think that the straight way is add a boolean field to your users table and check for thruthy value in a middleware, 5 minutes implementation, secured route forever , simple users management, no more passwords etc...

Answer (score 0):

besides middleware you can do simple check in controller (assuming you storing password hased, as it should be stored), just add password field in send sms form

```php
  $validated = request()->validate([
    'password' => 'required',
    // other rules here    
  ]);
  // take it from users table or where you're going to store passwords
  $hashedOriginal = Hash::make('smspassword');

  $isPasswordValid = Hash::check($validated['password'], $hashedOriginal);
  if (!$isPasswordValid) {
    abort('401');
  }
  // your send sms code next
```

in general middleware allowes you extend password protected functions very easy, so *if there is any chance* that sending sms is not the last password protected function **you'd better stick with middleware**